# How do I create a batch file to create many layers of folders from 2 different variable lists?

Tags: windows, batch-file, mkdir

I have ZERO experience with this. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Right now I have it so I can see the list of folders I am creating and edit which ones I want to create. I want to be able to create Fund Family folders and in each of those Fund Family folders have various entities and then within each entity create folders. I think this requires referencing many different outputlists. So like at the top the fundfamily list is fine...i think i need serval outpistlits for each funfamily that will contain the entities so entitylist01...entitylist02... if that makes sense

There are 32 fund families with around 600 entities in total. The entity list changes for each fund family.

this what I have so far...

```
mkdir C:\2013\"2 - November Projections"
pause
dir Z:\2013\"2 - November Projections"\"*" /b /a:d >fundfamily.txt
start C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe "fundfamily.txt"
pause
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (fundfamily.txt) do mkdir C:\2013\"2 - November Projections"\"%%~a"
pause
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (fundfamily.txt) do dir Z:\2013\"2 - November Projections"\"%%~a"\"*" /b /a:d >entitylist.txt
start C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe "entitylist.txt"
pause
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (entitylist.txt) do mkdir C:\2013\"2 - November Projections"\"*"\"%%~a"\2013\"November Estimates"
pause
```

Comment: Are you open to using a different (more full-featured) scripting language such as Perl, Python, or something similar?

Comment: It looks like your Z: drive already has the folders and you want to simply create them on the C: drive, duplicating the entire tree.  Is that correct?  If so, let me know and I'll change the following into an *answer*, so you can mark it correct: `robocopy "z:\2013\2 - November Projections" "c:\2013\2 - November Projections" /s /e /xf *`

Comment: Hey James, I appreciate the help. Let me elaborate a little more. The C: drive is actually going to be changed to Z: I only have it has C: right now so that I dont crash and screw up the share drive (z:). I want to make sure it does what I want before implementation. all of the folders are currently in place on the Z: drive.

Comment: The only folders that are not on place on the Z drive is the ones I want to create the 2013\November Projections within each entity that is in each fund family. The top 2013/"2 - November projections" folders are going to be renamed. The way it is currently set up was by 2013 and I am trying to fix it so that its my Fund Family. Inside the "2 - November projections" folder are other folders and documents I do not want to touch, which Is why i originally have the pause after the first outputlist to edit it.

Comment: I am more than open to using anything that will get the job done. I am hoping to have it set up so that this can be applicable to any sharedrive in the future which is why I'm trying to have the outlist pop up so i can manually choose which folders at the top if that makes sense

Comment: but with moving forward I want to have it set up as creating these folders even though they are currently in place so that I can do this for other engagements and future years. Copy is not the functionality I am looking for. Once I get this top part down I can go forward with doing everything else i have plans for like moving all files at the bottom level into the new folders I created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal
SET "sourcedrive=Z"
SET "destdrive=C"
SET /a year=2013
SET "projections=2 - November Projections"
SET "Estimates=November Estimates"
DIR /b /ad "%sourcedrive%:\%year%\%projections%" >fundfamily.txt
start /wait "Fund Family" C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe "fundfamily.txt"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (fundfamily.txt) DO (
 ECHO MD "%destdrive%:\%year%\%projections%\%%~a"
 DIR /b /ad "%sourcedrive%:\%year%\%projections%\%%~a" >entitylist.txt
 start /wait "%%~a entities" C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe "entitylist.txt"
 FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN (entitylist.txt) DO ECHO MD "%destdrive%:\%year%\%projections%\%%~a\%%~b\%year%\%estimates%"
)
```

It's incredibly difficult to solve a problem stated as ""my code doesn't do what I want it to do" without an indication of sample data or desired outcome.

For instance, you could provide a partial listing such as

`fundfamily.txt`

```
Jones
Brown
de la Vedova
Smith
```

`entitylist.txt`

```
Stock - Confusion Industries
Sweatshop Industrial Inc.
Royalties - Useless Invention
123, Slum St., Gloomsville
```

and a note like `the entity list changes for each fundfamily` - or renaims the same, or whatever. You can `Edit` this data into your question - 'tis what the `Edit` link under the tags is used for.

As for the above code - I've assumed that the structure is as I have indicated. I would suggest that it would be quite an onerous task if you have hundreds of `fundfamily` entries, but we have no further data to go on...so it's "air" code - untried for absence of available data.

Note that the first quoted string in the `start/wait` line becomes the window title. If you don't want a window title, use an empty string `""`

I've left `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe` in place, but it's quite likely that simply `notepad` would suffice, or even that it could be omitted entirely. The `/wait` is the magic - this waits until the executable is finished before the batch proceeds to the next step.

Also note that the `MD` commands (`MD` and `mkdir` are synonyms) are merely `echo`ed - so that you may test without actually changing anything. You'd need to remove the `echo` keyword before the `md` to actually create the directories.

Comment: PERFECT! I cannot thank you enough. would you mind helping me add more to this?  I am going to post another question using this as the building block.

Comment: Would you mind looking at my new question? it elaborates on what you have provided me. thanks!  @Magoo